# Invalid token character '/' in org.springframework.http.MediaType

Tags: rest, spring-boot, resttemplate, restful-url, media-type

I have a basic SpringBoot 2.1.5.RELEASE app. Using Spring Initializer, JPA, embedded Tomcat;

I want to create this MediaType

```
MediaType mediaType = new MediaType("application/vnd.bonanza+xml");
```

that in PostMan works fine, but not in RestTemplate

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:816)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:797)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:324)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
    at com.ideefecloud.IdeefeCloudApplication.main(IdeefeCloudApplication.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid token character '/' in token "application/vnd.bonanza+xml"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are may be using the wrong [constructor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/MediaType.html#MediaType-java.lang.String-). this constructor takes only *type* as *arguments* and *treats* subtype as `*`

Change:

```
MediaType mediaType = new MediaType("application/vnd.bonanza+xml");
```

To:

```
MediaType mediaType = MediaType.valueOf("application/vnd.bonanza+xml");
```

> **valueOf**
>
> `public static MediaType valueOf(String value)`
>
> Parse the given String value into a MediaType object, with this method
>   name following the 'valueOf' naming convention (as supported by
>   ConversionService.
>
> **Parameters**:
>
> value - the string to parse
>
> **Throws**:
>
> InvalidMediaTypeException - if the media type value cannot be parsed

OR:

```
MediaType mediaType = new MediaType("application", "vnd.bonanza+xml");
```

> `MediaType(String type, String subtype)`
>
> Create a new MediaType for the given primary type and subtype.

OR:

```
MediaType mediaType = MediaType.yourType;
```

Answer (score 2):

A media type consists of a *type* and a *subtype*.  To create an instance of [`MediaType`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/MediaType.html), you could either split type and subtype in the [constructor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/MediaType.html#MediaType-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), as shown below:

```java
MediaType mediaType = new MediaType("application", "vnd.bonanza+xml");
```

Or you could use the [`valueOf()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/MediaType.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-) factory method instead:

```java
MediaType mediaType = MediaType.valueOf("application/vnd.bonanza+xml");
```